# is it possible to get recipient status for a group of envelope IDs through DOCUSIGN API

Tags: docusignapi

I am aware that we can query a list of envelope Ids for getting the envelope status.

Example of the one i tried is

```
"https://DOMAIN/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCT_ID/envelopes?status=sent,delivered,signed,completed,declined,processing&envelope_ids=eID1,eID2,eID3"
```

But i am trying to understand if it is possible to get the recipient status for a list of envelopes.

please provide some online reference if this possible.

Thanks for reading!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible through one single call in the REST API. This however is possible with a single call in the SOAP API.

In REST, for each envelope you'd have to do the following call: https://{{server}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/re‌​cipients

If you're looking to get back all of the data from an envelope (or list of envelopes), SOAP is going to make this call a lot easier for you.

If you have a detailed workflow and are going to be sending out a lot of envelopes, I advise to attempt to keep your API call count to a minimum. Since it is hard limited to 1000 calls per clock hour (10:00:00-10:59:59, 11:00:00-11:59:59, etc).

[SOAP API Documentation - EnvelopeStatus](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf#page=68)

Comment: Ohh. But i was looking is there a way to achieve this by REST api. But thanks for the information thought

Comment: In REST, for each envelope you'd have to do the following call https://{{server}}/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients

Comment: yeah i was thinking there is a flag in envelope status to include "Recipient" as well.

Comment: Edited my response above with the correct information